# ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM Error

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssl, ssl-certificate

Many websites I try going to, I get the following error message:

[image]

I tried doing the following things:

- Delete history, cookies, etc.
- Clear SSL State
- `ipconfig /flushdns`
- `ipconfig /renew`

  - I get the following output:

`No operation can be performed on Ethernet while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 2 while it has its media disconnected.
No operation can be performed on Local Area Connection* 4 while it has its media disconnected.`

How can I fix the issue of `ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM`?

**Information:**

OS: Windows 10

Browser: Chrome and command line when uploading git to github

Comment: What browser are you using.  Edit your question to include this vital information.  Be sure to include what OS you are using

Comment: Chrome build?  Chrome has recently changed the requirements for certificates to be considered secure.  This certificate is likely an unsupported SHA-1 certificate.

Comment: @Ramhound Latest one, but the problem isn't only with chrome, since I can't access sites using cmd either.

Comment: Do you tend to save certificates locally? Do you have intermediate certificates saved or marked as roots?

Comment: @Ram I don't know the answer to both questions. How do I find out?

Comment: Go back to codepen.io, save the certificate you get the error from and post it here, I'll take a looksie.